# Asynchronous tests execute methods in other tests after their own tests have finished

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, integration-testing

When I execute my tests one by one, all tests work and there are no problems. However when I execute them all together, I will run into problems like `NullReferenceException` and `SemaphoreFullException`.

After a lot of digging I have noticed that the threads of my tests seem to interfere with eachother: even after the test has finished, (duplicated?) background calls seem to continue when another test is being executed.

The application in question is a WinRT Component executed from a Universal App Unit Test Project. All calls you'll see below are executed asynchronously. In order to give my backgroundtasks the time to finish (if the test continues while supposedly waiting for the asynchronous background task, it will shutdown once it reaches the end of the test) I put the main thread to sleep for an appropriate amount of time with

```
new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout: 60 * 1000);
```

Additionally I have also added a sleep to the teardown method to be very sure everything gets finished:

```
[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup()
{
   new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout: 60 * 1000);
}
```

In order to diagnose what I have so far, I have looked at the execution plan of the tests and since they're pretty similar I simply put a `Debug.WriteLine(session.GetHashCode())` in every relevant place where my code passes. Below you can find the result of that stripped from the `FileNotFoundExceptions` in mscorlib, end-of-thread messages and symbol loading messages.

This `Session` object in question is something that gets created by the user and passes it on to `Core` which then passes it on to `MainApi` and `StorageApi`. The former wraps this into a `Dispatcher` and passes this dispatcher onto `UserController` while `StorageApi` simply passes the session object to `StorageController` and subsequently `DatabaseController`.

Throughout the entire hierarchy the same session object is used and passed through and all objects use the reference that is available to them at their location.

The semaphore comes into play when a database is created. In the `EventBus` there is a property

```
internal static SemaphoreSlim TablesCreatedSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
```

which is used to make sure that there will be no data requested before the tables are created. This is used by placing

```
await EventBus.TablesCreatedSemaphore.WaitAsync();
```

between executing the `SuccesfulLogin` event and requesting data from the API and placing

```
EventBus.TablesCreatedSemaphore.Release();
```

Right after where the last table is created.

```
Integration_DownloadAsset_WithInvalidId_ThrowsSomeException
*************************************************
                   NEW EXECUTION
*************************************************
Core (ctor): 53578018
Main Api (ctor): 53578018
Api dispatcher (ctor): 53578018
UserController (ctor): 53578018
Storage Api (ctor): 53578018
Storage controller (ctor): 53578018
Database controller (ctor): 53578018
User controller (GetApiKeyAsync:pre-call): 53578018
Session (IsLoggedIn): 53578018
User controller (GetApiKeyAsync:pre-successfullogin-event): 53578018
Storage controller (CreateFolderStructure): 53578018
Database Controller(CreateDatabase): 53578018
Session (IsLoggedIn): 53578018
Session (IsLoggedIn): 53578018
Database controller (ctor): 53578018



Integration_DownloadAsset_WhenFileAlreadyExists_IsLocalReturnsTrue
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll


Integration_Login_WithValidLogin_RemovesUnusedAssetsFromFolder
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Integration_DownloadAsset_WithValidId_DownloadsFileToLocalFolder
*************************************************
                   NEW EXECUTION
*************************************************
Core (ctor): 20039337
Main Api (ctor): 20039337
Api dispatcher (ctor): 20039337
UserController (ctor): 20039337
Storage Api (ctor): 20039337
Storage controller (ctor): 20039337
Database controller (ctor): 20039337
User controller (GetApiKeyAsync:pre-call): 20039337
Session (IsLoggedIn): 20039337
User controller (GetApiKeyAsync:pre-successfullogin-event): 20039337
Storage controller (CreateFolderStructure): 53578018
Storage controller (CreateFolderStructure): 20039337
Database Controller(CreateDatabase): 53578018
Database Controller(CreateDatabase): 20039337
Session (IsLoggedIn): 20039337
Session (IsLoggedIn): 20039337
Database controller (ctor): 20039337

*************************************************
                   NEW EXECUTION
*************************************************
Core (ctor): 20995649
Main Api (ctor): 20995649
Api dispatcher (ctor): 20995649
UserController (ctor): 20995649
Storage Api (ctor): 20995649
Storage controller (ctor): 20995649
Database controller (ctor): 20995649
User controller (GetApiKeyAsync:pre-call): 20995649
Session (IsLoggedIn): 20995649
User controller (GetApiKeyAsync:pre-successfullogin-event): 20995649
Storage controller (CreateFolderStructure): 53578018
Storage controller (CreateFolderStructure): 20039337
Database Controller(CreateDatabase): 53578018
Database Controller(CreateDatabase): 20039337
Storage controller (CreateFolderStructure): 20995649
Database Controller(CreateDatabase): 20995649
Session (IsLoggedIn): 20995649
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

## Notes

- Each test shows its name by printing it to `Debug.WriteLine` but apparently the last one didn't do this.
- The two tests with an `Exception` are failed tests and might very well be correct exceptions.
- The first test only has hashcodes of the object it created, the second one has calls to its methods with an object that has the hashcode as the previous test and the last test has calls to its methods with hashcodes from both previous tests.
- These findings and my assumption fall in line with some other curious behaviour I have noticed (sometimes the `Session` object wouldn't have authentication information in one place but do have it elsewhere, or data would get inserted inside the database twice despite primary key conflicts - although I don't know why that even was possible in the first place).
- I have considered that might just be an issue of late-flushing the data to the output window but it seems a little to well-timed for that.
- Changing the execution order of the tests still causes the first two to succeed and the third one to fail. The behaviour is the same with every run: each test performs an extra call with the session object of each previous test.

## Example test

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Integration_DownloadAsset_WithValidId_DownloadsFileToLocalFolder()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Integration_DownloadAsset_WithValidId_DownloadsFileToLocalFolder");
  var core = new Core(new Session());
  await core.Api.GetApiKeyAsync(new GetApiKeyRequestParameters
  {
      // Authentication parameters
  });

  //TODO: why is this necessary?
  new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout: 60 * 1000);

  await core.Api.DownloadAssetAsync("1891");

  // Allow the program to download the file
  new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout: 60 * 1000);

  var localFolder = await (await (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Data")).GetFolderAsync("AccountData")).GetFolderAsync("Files");
  var fileNames = (await localFolder.GetFilesAsync()).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
  CollectionAssert.Contains(fileNames, "1891");
}
```

## Question

I believe the cause to be that method invocations somehow remain behind even when the test has finished. How is this possible and how can I prevent from tests to intertwine with eachother?

If this is not the cause, what is?

Comment: Are these actually *unit* tests? Or are they really integration tests? Because if they were unit tests, your API would be stubbed, it would execute synchronously and you wouldn't have this problem. You almost never have multiple threads involved in a proper unit test.

Comment: Ah, tagged it wrongly. They are integration tests (it's an API wrapper, integration is all there is to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of an anticlimax since as it turns out my mind was the bug.

I assumed incorrectly that I could make the events inside the `EventBus` (which transmits `OnSuccesfulLogin`) `static` since they are not meant to dynamically register listeners.

Since `static` elements are held on *AppDomain* level this means that for each execution of my tests would add its own connections to the already existing static listeners which causes the incremental buildup of calls.

By making `EventBus` a non-static type with instance fields, all tests now run as they should.

Thanks to @NETscape for putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with unit testing async methods and the gotchas:

[Async Unit Tests, Part 1: The Wrong Way](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html)

Solution

[Async Unit Tests, Part 2: The Right Way](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html)

- Install the [AsyncUnitTests-MSTest NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/AsyncUnitTests-MSTest) into your test
  project.
- Add a using Nito.AsyncEx.UnitTests; line.
- Change your
  [TestClass] attribute to [AsyncTestClass].

Example:

```
[TestMethod]
public async void FourDividedByTwoIsTwoAsync()
{
    int result = await MyClass.Divide(4, 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result);
}
```

Comment: I might have a fix going now (it's testing) so this might not be the solution but the remarks in there about asynchronous tests are relevant to my awaiting of the threads. Could you incorporate this in your answer so it isn't just a few links?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel hope it works. Updated answer to include important bits of the blog post.

Comment: The AsyncUnitTests package was only intended for VS2010; the op is using VS2013.